# Cosmos DB - Unable to retreive from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB database and try to retrieve some documents with Xamarin, but I failed !

As expected, I used the following package :
  Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.9.1 
  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core

I have tried to follow the MS Documentation here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/cosmosdb/consuming

The problem is that it uses some functions that doesn't exists!
By example :

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TodoItem>(collectionLink).AsDocumentQuery();
while (query.HasMoreResults) Items.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TodoItem>());
```

The AsDocumentQuery, HasMoreResults, ExecuteNextAsync are not there !!

I have try this :

```
        var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Item>(collectionUri);
        var enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var item = enumerator.Current;
        }
```

But my "Item" are empty, not initialized at all !

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: `ExecuteNextAsync`, `HasMoreResults`, etc.. are in the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq` namespace so add a using clause, i.e. `using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things: 
add the line

using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;

Second, make sure your collection is not empty. Go to portal and add a document and then try your code.

Code should work with 1.9.1 but feel free to upgrade.